# How do I reset my Node dependencies (Gatsby, Netlify and NVM issue)

Tags: node.js, dependencies, version, gatsby, sharp

I recently started using NVM but doing so inadvertently broke my Gatsby site dependencies, specifically the Sharp dependency. I'm using Node 10.16.0, but I think the error was caused by running an install with Node 12.

The issue is that some of my modules are not being imported properly - specifically typography.js, but I think the problem is with the Sharp package. I was having build problems on Netlify until I cleared the cache and rebuilt, and now everything works in deployment. The issue is something being cached on my local machine I think.

So I've tried the following:

- deleting the package-lock.json
- deleting node_modules and running npm install or yarn install
- Deleting the cache and public folders in my project dir

None of these has worked so far.

Here's the package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.19",
        "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.9.0",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.9.0",
        "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.4",
        "@glidejs/glide": "^3.3.0",
        "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "gatsby": "^2.8.5",
        "gatsby-background-image": "^0.2.74",
        "gatsby-image": "^2.1.2",
        "gatsby-plugin-express": "^1.1.6",
        "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.1.1",
        "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^2.1.1",
        "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.0.12",
        "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.1.3",
        "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "^3.0.7",
        "gatsby-plugin-typography": "^2.2.13",
        "gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files": "^2.0.13",
        "gatsby-remark-images": "^3.0.14",
        "gatsby-remark-prismjs": "^3.2.10",
        "gatsby-source-contentful": "^2.0.67",
        "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.0.38",
        "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.3.12",
        "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.1.21",
        "prismjs": "^1.16.0",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react": "^16.8.6",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
        "react-glider": "^1.1.2",
        "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
        "react-pure-lifecycle": "^3.0.0",
        "react-scroll": "^1.7.11",
        "react-typography": "^0.16.19",
        "sharp": "^0.22.1",
        "styled-components": "^4.2.1",
        "typography": "^0.16.19",
        "typography-theme-lawton": "^0.16.19"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "gatsby-plugin-remove-trailing-slashes": "^2.0.11",
        "nodemon": "^1.19.1",
        "prettier": "^1.17.1"
    },
```

It would be great to have any suggestions about how I can reset the dependencies...Many thanks.

Comment: Try deleting `~/.npm` on Posix, or `%AppData%/npm-cache` on Windows. That said, you might also want to check your dependency versions against a previous version in your source control.

Comment: That’s a great idea, thanks. I’m on MacOS btw